# Multiple RDP Sessions - Check if available

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp, windows-server-2019, remote-desktop-services

I RDP to many Windows Servers.  Some servers allow only the standard two RDP sessions, and I am careful to log off when I am done.  Other servers allow many sessions, so I prefer to disconnect to keep my applications open.

I cannot always check Local Group Policy as I am not an admin of many of these servers.  I hope to find evidence somewhere, available to a standard user: query local group policy, registry setting, query for a Windows feature setting, query terminal services, power shell command, etc.

**Question:** How can a standard user account check, if a Windows Server is has the Remote Desktop Application Server role installed and allows more than the two administrative RDP sessions?

Comment: The Local Group Policy editor requires admin rights, but I think a standard user can read the values.  Where are the settings stored: admx file or registry maybe?

Answer (score 2):

An indirect way would be to just check that registry key:

**LicenseServers** (REG_SZ)
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services

If set it mean the server is allocating RDS CAL to non admin user/device connecting to that server.

If unset and using a standard account you would got an licence warning in the grace period and a connection refused after the grace period.

Answer (score 0):

You can't only someone with administrative permissions on the rdp configuration can check that. Ask an administrator to check that for you.